# Use responsewriter anywhere in golang application - middleware

Tags: http, go

I have a single endpoint which is fairly complex and runs algorithms from quite a few different files. I'm using an http handler as described in the docs:

```
http.Handle("/foo", fooHandler)

http.HandleFunc("/bar", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(r.URL.Path))
})
```

I want to write http responses in case of errors but don't want to have to pass the writer down 3 functions deep to achieve this. How would I write a middleware allowing me to access the responsewriter and return a response anywhere in the application?

Comment: I'll leave an opinion in a comment because I want to see what others think as well: *don't* pass RW (`ResponseWriter`) down deep into different levels. Modularize your code instead. Almost everything should just return an `error` for errors, and only the top-level handler should write HTTP errors in response to these. This will also help you make the majority of your code more easily testable

Comment: What @EliBendersky says is spot-on. Don't pass the RW down--pass errors up instead.

Comment: In many cases it helps to change the middleware function signature to something easier to deal with. One option is to have a top-level MW that creates a context from the reader, writer, and other items, pass it down to a func(ctx) error, and then deal with the error returned from that function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to summarize in an answer what I mentioned in the comment, with some additional details.

Let's say your handler H calls F, which calls G, which calls J.

Preferred approach: *Don't* pass a `ResponseWriter` all the way through to F/G/J. Instead, F, G, J should return values, including `error` for errors, and `H` should build up the response and write to a `ResponseWriter`. This makes your code more modular, easier to test in isolation and easier to reuse.

Testability is important; assume your function J does some computation which may result in an error. If it just returns `error`, this is trivial to test - all you need are J's inputs, and then you can assert that you get the expected errors in some scenarios. If instead of returning an `error`, J takes a `ResponseWriter`, you'll need to create a fake `ResponseWriter` and verify that the right errors get written into it. This is much more complicated.